# Equations aligned center

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, numbering, align, subequations

The following code

```
\begin{equation} \label{eq:test}
\begin{aligned} 
A=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\
B=BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB\\
C=CCCCC, D=DDDDDDD\\    
E=EEEEE, F=FFFFFFF
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

Alligns the equations from right while I need them to be at the center. Using `gather`  does not allow me to give number to my equation. What is the standard way to implement what I intend to do?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried replacing `aligned` with `gathered`?

Comment: @Mico, Yes and here is the result: `Package amsmath Error: \begin{gather} allowed only in paragraph mode \begin{gather}`

Comment: Note that I wrote `gathered`, not `gather`. (See also the code in my answer.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to have each equation *centered* rather than aligned on some specific point (such as the first `=` symbol), you should use a `gathered` environment instead of an `aligned` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:test}
\begin{gathered}
A=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\
B=BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB\\
C=CCCCC, D=DDDDDDD\\
E=EEEEE, F=FFFFFFF
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 6):

**Edit:** I automatically assumed that you wanted all the equations aligned on the `=` sign. The right answer to center them is Mico's. However, this is another possibility that you may try.

You only need to tell Latex how to align your equations, with the `&` symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:test}
    \begin{aligned} 
        A &= AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\
        B &= BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB\\
        C &= CCCCC, D=DDDDDDD\\    
        E &= EEEEE, F=FFFFFFF
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: I believe the OP wants the equations centered rather than aligned on, say, the first `=` symbol.

Comment: @MarcoG, but this OP doesn't like to have. From its questions follows, that it like to have centered. This is obtained with `gathered` math environment. In it the use of ampersand `&` has not sense, so their is not allowed.

Comment: @Mico@Zarko of course you're right! I saw the `aligned` environment and automatically assumed that the OP wanted these equations with the `=` aligned. So, how should they be centered?

Comment: To center the equations, don't use an `aligned` environment. Instead, as @Zarko and I have already commented, a `gathered` environment should be used.

Comment: @Mico Ok, I'm just not used to center equations :-)! In your opinion, should I delete my answer, or should I keep it to show the OP another possibility (even if it is a quite "basic" answer)?

Comment: Given that there's already another answer that uses the `gathered` environment, you may want to simply re-write your existing answer to extol the advantages of actually using an alignment point when using the `aligned` environment.